# Promise {<pending>} Graphql, and strapi with nextjs

Tags: next.js, graphql, strapi

With GraphQL and nextjs, I'm trying to retrieve some data from strapi.

When I try to access these data from the other file and display them on the UI, I get this error Promise {} in console.log.

This is what i tried

```
sliderAdapter.js

import { fetchSlider } from "./apiClient";

export const sliderAdapter = async (data, locale, url) => {
  const sl = await fetchSlider();
  const deepDownSlides = sl.data?.slides?.data;

  if (deepDownSlides.length > 0) {
    const slider = deepDownSlides[0]?.attributes?.slider;

    // console.log("slider", slider);
    return slider;
  }
  //   This code is working but not properly, just return the data into the console.

  return "";
};
```

#### fetchSlider is the file where i put the query.

Next:

```
    import { sliderAdapter } from "../../lib/sliderAdapter";

  const Slider = (data) => { 
  const slide= sliderAdapter(data)
  console.log("slide", slide)
```

If anyone knows or can find the issues, plz let me know :)

Answer (score 1):

Your function is asynchronous so you have to retrieve the value once the promise is resolved

```js
sliderAdapter(data).then(slide=>console.log(slide))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but this does not return anything

Comment: Error: Network error: Response not successful: Received status code 400

Comment: Oh, it was a mistake in the query. got it.
Thanks